# Regarding sorting a Map

Tags: java

I have one query , I have developed a Map which I want to sort  please advise..

```
  HashMap map=new HashMap();//HashMap key random order.
     map.put("Amit","Java");
     map.put("Saral","J2EE");
     map.put("ty","Spring");
     map.put("Anupam","Hibernate");
     map.put("Ravi",".Net");
     map.put("Saral","Andriod");//same key but different value 
     map.put("Nitin","PHP");
     map.put("hj","Spring1");
     System.out.println("There are "+map.size()+" elements in the map.");
     System.out.println("Content of Map are...");
     Set s=map.entrySet();
     Iterator itr=s.iterator();
     while(itr.hasNext())
     {
         Map.Entry m=(Map.Entry)itr.next();
         System.out.println(m.getKey()+"\t"+m.getValue()+"\t"+ m.hashCode());
      }
```

Comment: `HashMap` has no concept of ordering, so you will need a different data structure or will have to copy your data to something that has ordering. Now the question is whether or not you want always-ordered or ordering on demand.

Comment: didn't get that please show the demo, if possible then take the upper one code and on the same show the ordering that will be a great help..!!thanks in advance..!!

Comment: @user why don't you try it out for yourself? It might help to read some resources online.

Comment: My question is do you want your data to always be ordered? Dilum's answer of using a `TreeMap` would always keep your data ordered based on your map's keys (Which are `string`s). If you added a new entry into the `TreeMap`, the tree would maintain ordering correctly. "Ordering on demand" means that you don't care about how the data is ordered, and only sometimes will you actually care about ordering/sorting.

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to be sorted by (string) keys, then simply use `java.util.TreeMap` instead of a `HashMap`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things to consider which will affect what the solution you want really is.

You are using a `HashMap<K, V>`, which implies you want the association and key lookup behavior of a `Map`-type.

`HashMap` itself does not care about ordering - whenever you insert a key-value pair, the key's `hashCode()` method is called and the map stores the pairing using that hash code. `String` objects already have a correct `hashCode()` implementation, so you can use them as keys as you do without problem.

Of course, when it comes to retrieving or iterating over your `HashMap`, you will get things in a pretty much random order because the hash map stores items by the hash code, and ordering can change every time you add/remove an object.

Since you want to "sort" your data, I assume you mean you want your pairings back, ordered by key (sorted by the names you put in).

#### Now here are where the considerations come in:

### Keeping Data Always Sorted

If you want your data to always be sorted, meaning every time you insert a new key-value pair, that you want to keep the natural ordering of elements, then there are some convenient data structures in the Java API you can use:

#### Using `TreeMap`

As Dilum already mentioned, you can use [`java.util.TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), which implements the [`java.util.SortedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) interface, which will guarantee an ordering to the keys in the map.

Example:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class SortedMapExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SortedMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        map.put("Amit","Java");
        map.put("Saral","J2EE");
        map.put("ty","Spring");
        map.put("Anupam","Hibernate");
        map.put("Ravi",".Net");
        map.put("Saral","Andriod");//same key but different value 
        map.put("Nitin","PHP");
        map.put("hj","Spring1");

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : map) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%s - %s", e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
        }
    }
}
```

You will get this back if you run this code:

```
λ > java SortedMapExample
Amit - Java
Anupam - Hibernate
Nitin - PHP
Ravi - .Net
Saral - Andriod
hj - Spring1
ty - Spring
```

#### Using `ConcurrentSkipListMap`

[ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) is a newer data structure, first available with Java 6. It also implements the `SortedMap` interface, with an underlying implementation involving [skip lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list).

It is also a concurrent collection, which you can read more about in this [article from Brian Goetz](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp07233/index.html). Java Concurrent Collections live in `java.util.concurrent`, and to be brief, are high performance thread-safe collections.

It's easy enough to alter the previous example to using a `ConcurrentSkipListMap`.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap; // this changed

public class SortedMapExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // the following line changed - now you know the power of programming to interfaces
        SortedMap<String, String> map = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, String>();
        map.put("Amit","Java");
        map.put("Saral","J2EE");
        map.put("ty","Spring");
        map.put("Anupam","Hibernate");
        map.put("Ravi",".Net");
        map.put("Saral","Andriod");//same key but different value 
        map.put("Nitin","PHP");
        map.put("hj","Spring1");

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : map) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%s - %s", e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
        }
    }
}
```

Run this code, you'll get the exact same output:

```
λ > java SortedMapExample
Amit - Java
Anupam - Hibernate
Nitin - PHP
Ravi - .Net
Saral - Andriod
hj - Spring1
ty - Spring
```

### Sorting on Demand

Perhaps in your use case, you don't want to always keep your data sorted. Maybe it's a performance concern (please benchmark that if that is your concern), and you really only need to sort data when requested.

You can, in your case, use [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) on the keys of your data.

Sticking with your `HashMap` example:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UnsortedExample {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
      map.put("Amit", "Java");
      map.put("Saral","J2EE");
      map.put("ty","Spring");
      map.put("Anupam","Hibernate");
      map.put("Ravi",".Net");
      map.put("Saral","Andriod");//same key but different value
      map.put("Nitin","PHP");
      map.put("hj","Spring1");

      List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());
      Collections.sort(keys);

      for (String key : keys) {
          System.out.println(String.format("%s - %s", key, map.get(key)));
      }
   }
}
```

Here I pulled the `keySet()` from the map, which returns a `Set` object containing all the keys in the map. I then turned that into an `ArrayList` and sorted the list, then iterated over the list and pulled the value out of the map.

You can also use `java.util.TreeSet` when you pull out the `keySet()`, and `TreeSet` is naturally ordered just like `TreeMap` and `ConcurrentSkipListMap`.

Example of using a `SortedSet`:

`java.util.SortedSet<String> keys = new java.util.TreeSet<String>(map.keySet());`

As an aside, there is a `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap` class as well, which is the Java Concurrency version of `java.util.HashMap` and works very well in multi-threaded environments where concurrent access will occur.

### Whoa whoa, why is the ordering weird?

This example is using English (I don't know much about 'sorted' non-English languages), but you can see that there is some strangeness in the ordering.

For example, in the output in the previous examples, `"hj"` came after `"Saral"`, whereas a human would probably order the list truly alphabetically, such that `"hj"` came between `"Anupam"` and `"Nitin"`.

By default, `java.lang.String` implements the `Comparable` interface, defining a [natural ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). Java, like pretty much every other programming language in use, orders capital English letters before lowercase letters.

The simple explanation is that in ASCII/UTF-8, English capital letters come before English lowercase letters.

However, you might want a different alphabetical sort which ignores case. For that you will have to write your own class that implements `Comparator`, and pass it to the constructor of `TreeMap` or `ConcurrentSkipListMap`, or to the `Collections.sort` method that takes a comparator object.

I'll leave that as an exercise to you if you want to achieve such an ordering.

### Conclusion

Your question, on the surface, is just about sorting the data in your `Map`-like object.

You have the option to use:

- `java.util.TreeMap` - keeps ordering of elements by natural order
- `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap` - same as above, but comes with good thread-safety
- Sort on demand using `Collections.sort()`

I don't know what your use for this data structure or what environment it is being used in. 
For example, if there is multithreaded access to your `HashMap`, then you need synchronization mechanisms which `HashMap` by itself doesn't have. For that, it's easier to use `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap` or `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashmap`.

So depending on how you are using your data, there are different ways to have your data sorted. If you want always-sorted, then I'd recommend using `ConcurrentSkipListMap` (for multithreaded) or `TreeMap`. If you need the insertion performance of `HashMap`, which is amortized O(1), then you probably need to be using `HashMap` and sorting the "on demand" way, or keeping a separate data structure to order your keys. Do profiling if you have performance concerns for your specific use.

And some additional details:

- I am using [for each loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) to traverse my data structures above. If you only need element access (and not mutation/deletion), for-each is very nice syntactic sugar over explicit iterators.
- In my examples I use the interface as my variable's type, rather than the concrete class (in your code, you have `HashMap<...> map = new HashMap<...>();`. Generally it's a good idea to [program to interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) unless you have very exact requirements that necessitate using something specifically.